# Key for Am-G-F-D

Tags: theory

writing a song, verse in key of F, F Dm Bb C then the chorus is Am-G-F-D... I know Dm is the vi of the F key, but Dmaj sounds like I want.  Tried 7ths and other combos but this sounds best for my song.  I thought maybe it is now in key of C vi-V-IV-II, with the Dmaj being a II instead of a ii?

Comment: You seem comfortable with the idea of D as the II of C; why not as the VI of F?

Comment: Since the verse and pre-chorus is in F, yes, I'd prefer to keep it in F, but the F key ii is Gm,  I use a Gmaj, and my Chord Wheel tool doesn't show the G as an optional II chord, but DOES show the D as a II option in key of C, lol.

Answer (score 1):

You join a long line of questioners who are under the misapprehension that all chords (and indeed notes) need to be diatonic! It's just not true! Take a good look at several of your favourite songs, and you'll find that's so!

You *could* use D major in key F, and you *could* use D major in key C. It's not necessarily the actual chords used in a song which dictate its key. It's where in the song it feels at rest, at home, a place where the song could finish, without a feeling that there must be more to come before that ending arrives.

So, if you feel F is a home point, or that C sounds more final, is up to you. Often (not always) there will be a perfect cadence (V>I) at that point. In key F it's C>F, in key C it's G>C. That's sometimes a clue. Your choice - trust your ears!

EDIT: and stop using that chord wheel. I think I've just found the cause of many misguided questions received on this site!!

Comment: thanks... I have no problem with using a II instead of a ii for the key if it sounds right, I just   run into difficulty when building a chorus, verse, bridge from the main key.  SOme songs I keep everything in one key, but some I try to be adventurous and build some variations in the structure.  Adding a bridge, for example, may sound fine in a different key by itself, but the transition back to the original song key may not sound as I had hoped, so I want to figure out what key the bridge is to compare to the verse, chorus, or tag.

Comment: Getting back to original key isn't too difficult - ii>V>I is a well tried and tested sequence.

Answer (score 0):

1. To add to Tim's answer, what you mention is a **progression**, i.e. a series of chords.
2. What you do not mention is the **melody** these two progressions support.
3. Assuming, you do not change the key along the way, the **melody**:

- may or may not start at the root note of the key
- but will almost certainly end at the **root (tonic)**.

This is what Tim phrased "feel at home".

4. Only once you stated the melody and revealed its key (or more generic its scale), you can start to relate chords to this scale, i.e. analyse

- **degrees** (like I, iv, V)
- **chord structure** (**M**AJOR-ish like **I**maj7 / **m**inor-ish like b**iv**).

5. It also may so happen that your **chords**:

- are ordinary 3-tone-chords *(like I // c-e-g in key of C)*
- extended 4-tone-chords or beyond *(Imaj7 // c-e-g-b)*
- incomplete chords *(e.g. dropping the 3rd to fit with both major and minor, like I(omit 3) // c-g // power chord)*
- inverted chords *(think of reordering the notes along pitches/octaves, like C/G // g-c-e)*

6. To repeat, the functional meaning of the **chord progressions** become evident after you know the **key of the melody** (or more generic the scale).
7. The reverse may be true many times: a series of chords determines the **subset of notes picked from the 12 in one octave**. This many times results in 1, few or even 0 compatible **scales**. If it resolves, check if that's really the key of your melody: some chords may simply turn out to be wrong (i.e. badly chosen) in hindsight. If it's 0, you have either too many or too few notes in your chords to determine it as a common scale.
8. To further illustrate, we can chose 0 notes from 12 notes per octave, 1 from 12, ... 5 from 12 (can be pentatonics), ... 7 from 12 (can be major or minor, and many more), ... 12 from 12 scales. Many may sound silly or even hurtful, not so few open musical worlds, like Dorian. In total there are 2**12 = 4.096 such **theoretical scales**, where the 12 major keys and the 3 minor keys with 12 root notes are just a subset (i.e. 48 **scales** out of 4.096). While we just know 2 * 12 = 24 **keys** from classical music.
9. Whatever you do, as Tim said: trust your **ears**.

Comment: wow, I'm not formally trained in music, so it's an uphill battle, but I'm learning.  In this song, I've been trying to write compelling chord combinations for the musical parts, then write a melody in the same key as the part initially.  This is for a worship style, but strays from the usual simple structure to a harder rock concept with non-standard parts, if that makes sense.  thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks. Don‘t worry, just eat one elephant at a time, and one day music theory reveals its practical beauty. Keep trying, wondering, improving.

Answer (score 0):

Am-G-F-D is basically a non-diatonic chord progression in Am, why try and label it as C or F? You just have a song that has a verse in F and modulates to Am for the chorus. It isn’t much of a stretch. The C chord at the end of the verse doesn’t have a tonic flavor since it is a V that resolves back to the F upon repeating (I’m assuming those 4 chord progressions are repeated at least once).

Am and D, or i and IV are very commonly used together (think “Oye Como Va” among others). The major IV chord in a minor key comes from the Dorian mode, although this progression is not Dorian because of the F chord, it just momentarily hints at it.